# How do you access the for loop of the parent component within a child component which has the inputs?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular

So I am stuck on this. I am trying to get the Parent component to talk or integrate with the child component. 
Here is the parent component which basically has the for loop used to iterate or generate more links if a user wants to add more or presses the button to add more.

```
<div class="section url-wrapper">
    <div *ngFor="let url of urls; let i = index;" class="link input-wrapper">
            <childComponent></childComponent>
      <button class="button bad icon-only" (click)="removeURL(i)">
        <i class="far fa-times"></i>
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The parent component should only be able to register and display the output of the child component.

This is an example of the child component

```
<div class="section url-wrap">
    <input aria-label="URL Title" placeholder="Title" type="text" [value]="urls[i].title" (ngModel)="urls[i].title" name="url.title.{{ i }}"
        (input)="updateTitle(i, $event.target.value)">

          <input aria-label="URL" placeholder="https://example.com" type="text" [value]="urls[i].url" (ngModel)="urls[i].url" name="url.url.{{ i }}"
          (input)="updateUrl(i, $event.target.value)">   
 </div>
```

I need help both allowing the parent component to register input from the child component and being able to iterate from the for loop from the parent if it is possible.

> Please let me know if you need more information such as the component files or clarification

Comment: To allow the parent component to register input from the child component, you use what are called [Event Emitters](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/b/infragistics/posts/understanding-output-and-eventemitter-in-angular) see also the [official docs](https://angular.io/api/core/EventEmitter)

Comment: @mhodge But will event emitters allow the for loop to processed in the child component?

Comment: I don't understand that part of the question. What do you mean by "process the for loop in the child component"?

Comment: So you'll see in the parent component where I have a ngFor loop
`<div *ngFor="let url of urls; let i = index;" class="link input-wrapper">`
would an event emitter be able to register the array indexes?

Comment: Do you mean "have access to the url for that iteration of `*ngFor`? If so, that is what the `@Input()` directive is for. You can pass the url to the child like so, `<childComponent [url]="url"></childComponent>`. Then, in your child component, declare a property by saying `@Input() url;`. The value will be available at the time the `ngOnInit()` lifecycle hook executes.

Comment: The `@Output()` directive sends data from the child to a parent. The `@Input()` directive (on a child) receives data from the parent.

Comment: I will try this out once I am home but that makes perfect sense! so this will easily create the output for parent component?

Comment: I will work up an example for you and post it as an answer, so you can see how it all works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The below code & example will demonstrate how data flows from parent -> child -> parent by using the `@Input()` and `@Output()` directives.

[Working Example Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/parent-child-dataflow-example?file=src%2Fapp%2Fparent%2Fparent.component.ts)

### parent.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <div class="section url-wrapper">
      <div *ngFor="let url of urls" class="link input-wrapper">
        <app-child [url]="url" (updateUrl)="onUrlUpdate($event)"></app-child>
      </div>
    </div>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  public urls = [
    {url: "https://example.com", title: "Example1"},
    {url: "https://example.com", title: "Example2"},
    {url: "https://example.com", title: "Example3"},
  ]
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }

  onUrlUpdate($event) {
    // completely overkill, but just used to demonstrate a point
    var url = this.urls.find(_url => {
      // we can see here that the $event.url is actually the same object as the urls[i] that was
      // passed to the child. We do not lose the reference when it is passed to the child or back
      // up to the parent. 
      return $event.url === _url
    });
    if (url) {
      url[$event.prop] = $event.newValue;
    }
    console.log(`Updated URL's "${$event.prop}" property with the value "${$event.newValue}"`);
  }

}
```

### child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
  <div class="section url-wrap">
    <input aria-label="URL Title" placeholder="Title" type="text" [value]="url.title"
        (input)="handleUrlUpdate($event, 'title')"/>

    <input aria-label="URL" placeholder="https://example.com" type="text" [value]="url.url"
        (input)="handleUrlUpdate($event, 'url')"/>   
 </div>
  `,
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() url; // passed in from parent via [url] property on <app-child>
  @Output() updateUrl = new EventEmitter();
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // this.url is now available for the life of the child component (assuming it was passed by the parent)
  }

  handleUrlUpdate($event, propToUpdate) {
    // overkill, but used to demonstrate a point
    this.updateUrl.emit({url: this.url, prop: propToUpdate, newValue: $event.target.value});
  }

}
```

Comment: For some reason I wasn't able to access the link with the example but your solution definitely answered my question and makes sense!  My only question is is the public urls array filled with expected output? or did you purposely append the example data in there?

Comment: @B.Allen The public urls array is just filled with the example data. You can populate that list however you choose. It will push the urls to the child component and render them accordingly. Also, I fixed the link above, so you should have access to the working example now

Comment: thank you so much! This definitely helped me understand how component nesting works and to have a better understanding of how components work in angular!

Answer (score 2):

The stardard way to let components speack each others is with input-output:

You can pass values from parent to children with @Input for example:

**Parent code:**

```
<childComponent [someInputValue]="hello"></childComponent>
```

**Children code:**

```
@Input() someInputValue; //this property will be "hello"
```

and you can pass values (after being triggered) from children to parent:

**Children code:**

```
  @Output() itemSelectedOutput: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  buttonClicked() {
   this.itemSelectedOutput.emit("clicked");
  }
```

**Parent code:**

```
    <childComponent [someInputValue]="hello" (itemSelectedOutput)="someParentMethod($event)"></childComponent>

someParentMethod(event: any) {
 console.log(event);
}
```

You can reach the same thing with `ISubscription` but I suggest you to use the way above

Hope it can help

Comment: I get it, basically the `[someInputValue]="hello"` will print this in the parent component and the same rule can be applied if we wanted to register the users input correct?

Comment: @B.Allen with input you pass a value belonging to the parent component to the children component. You have to imagine components like boxes where you can’t see outside of them if not with input and output parameters that are ways to link each others. Anyway, yes you can pass everything you want, Objects too. If you found my answer right please check it as best answer:)

Comment: Thank you I understand it makes sense! I now see how both the parent component can talk to the child component especially with with input and output.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way in particular. If the children have to know about the parents, then your architecture should be adjusted